# How to check rate_limit_status in response header in C#

Tags: c#, twitter

We see that our rate limit is being reached in our Twitter calls, I did some research:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

They suggested checking this rate_limit_status once in a while explained here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status

So, I would like to know how to check that in the code. Can I do something like this?

```
string rateLimit = twitterService.Response.Headers["application/rate_limit_status"];
```

My questions are:

1. Do I then just parse the rateLimit? Because it is a JSON/XML
2. According to the API, it contains

   ```
   "remaining":
   "reset":
   "limit":
   ```

So, let's say I want to reset the rate limit once it hits closer to the limit, what should I do?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> do i then just parse the rateLimit?because it is a JSON/XML

Yes, for example using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

> if I want to reset the rate limit once it hits closer to the limit, what should I do?

You can't do anything but wait until the `reset` moment, it's a timestamp.

Comment: Ok, I am using TweetSharp API, I am not sure how I should reset the rate limite. It seems that you can only reset time stamp though. Any ideas?

Comment: @doglin you **cannot** reset the rate limit. Twitter keeps record on the amount of API calls you make. If you exceed the limit, you'll have to wait.

Comment: what is a good time to wait? 5 seconds? i calculated this value based on the definition in their API doc

Comment: what exactly do you mean by divide the number of times you can request over 15 minutes? The API says 15 calls every 15 minute, or 180 calls every 15 minute. I mean if I go by 15 calls every 15 minutes, that means, I should sleep for 3600 seconds between each call right? if I go by 180 calls every 15 minutes , then that is 5 seconds between each call. Am I interpreting that correctly? –